# translate site content: Use of undefined constant locale - assumed 'locale

Tags: php, laravel

The select allows the user to select 1 of 3 languages (english, spanish and german). The goal is that if the user select english, all content of the site changes to english, and the same for the other languages.

However there is this error:

> "Use of undefined constant locale - assumed 'locale'".

The LanguageController:

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function changeLanguage(Request $request)
    {
        if(Session::has(locale)){
            session()->set('locale', $request->language);}
        else{
            session()->set('locale', 'en');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Html:

```
    <form method="post" action="{{route('site.translate')}}" id="translate">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <select name="language">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="de">German</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

LocaleMiddleware:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class LocaleMiddleware
    {

        protected $languages = ['en','fr','es', 'de'];


        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if(!session()->has('locale'))
            {
                session()->put('locale', $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->languages));
            }

            app()->setLocale(session('locale'));

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Code to submit the form on select menu change:

```
var myFormName = "translate";
$('#language').on('change', function() {
            document.forms[myFormName].submit();
        });
```

Comment: `if(Session::has(locale)){`  `locale` is a constant `'locale'` is a string

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around locale ...   so...

if(Session::has(locale)){

change to

if(Session::has('locale')){

--
SYNTAX TIP:

```
variable = $var
constant = const
string = 'string'
```

Comment: Thanks, now it appears another error, the user is redirected to "proj.test/lang" and it appears  "Call to ubdnefined method Illuinate\Session\Store::set() in Illuminate/Support/Manager.php. Do you know why?

Comment: @Carrick try `->put('locale', 'en')` instead of  `::set` maybe.

Comment: Thanks, like that dont appear any error but the site content is not translated.